# ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo

After upgrading from Expo SDK 47 to Expo SDK 48, I'm getting Android and iOS to build successfully, but whenever I try to pull up the iOS app, I get this error:

ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

And I cannot figure out what the problem is. I've looked it up on stack overflow and on multiple different sites and can't seem to find an answer for it.

Here's everything in my package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo/dev-server": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@native-html/table-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@types/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "axios-hooks": "^3.0.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.1.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-store-review": "~6.2.1",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.0.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "moti": "^0.17.1",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-autolink": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.0",
    "react-native-draggable-dynamic-flatlist": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "^0.0.14",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "13.0.1",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.13",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-pulse": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-swipeable-item": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.21",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11"
  },
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out the issue. Had to update `"pusher-js": "^7.0.6"` to `"pusher-js": ^8.2.0`

Comment: thanks for posting your solution! CONFIRMED this works to resolve the error for expo 49 too.